# std::unordered_map gives error when inserting using emplace function

Tags: c++

I'm getting this weird error when inserting an element into `std::unordered_map` using `emplace` function but not if I use `operator[]` function overload. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

class B {
public:
    B() = default;
    ~B() = default; 
};

class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;
    
    std::unique_ptr<B> b_ptr;
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, A> mp;
    // mp.emplace("abc", A()); // gives compiler here
    auto& a = mp["def"];
}
```

I'm getting huge error print when compiled. This is a short note of error: `template argument deduction/substitution failed`

Comment: whats yous compiler vendor/version? Clang and GCC are ok with this code

Comment: @EduardRostomyan GCC 9.2

Comment: Simplified problem: `std::pair<const std::string, A> p { "abc", A{} };`. Adding move constructor into `A` can resolve it: `A(A&&) = default;`. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/5rEYcdro6.

Comment: @NathanOliver doesn't `emplace` create `class A` object in place when inserting?

Comment: @Harry No, it creates map's value type in place, which is `std::pair<const std::string,A>` in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `emplace` like `mp.emplace("abc", A());` what you are doing is creating a temporary `A`, and that object is then copied/moved into the object that `emplace` is going to construct.  When you did `~A() = default;` in the class, that gets rid of the compiler supplied default move constructor, and the copy constructor is implicitly deleted because `std::unique_ptr` can't be copied so the `A()` can't be moved or copied into the object `emplace` is going to create.

You can fix this by using the `std::piecewise_construct` taged version of emplace to forward the parts of the key value pair to `emplace` like

```
mp.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,    // call the piecewise_construct overload
          std::forward_as_tuple("abc"), // forwards "abc" to the key
          std::forward_as_tuple());     // forwards nothing to the value so it can be default constructed
```

or you could just add a move constructor to `A` using

```
A(A&&) = default;
```

so that `emplace` can move the `A()` you created in `main` into `mp`.

Comment: What you say is a work around but the issue is that `A` is not movable... one just needs to add move ctor/assignment to `A`, or rather to declare them defaulted.

Comment: @ALX23z IIRC, mapped type doesn't need to be copyable/movable with unordered maps. Or, does it?

Comment: @DanielLangr `unordered_map` can work with such types. But it doesn't look like OP was looking for the non-movable and non-copyable case.

Comment: @ALX23z While adding a move constructor will get the original code to work, and I've added that in, doing so might incur a performance penalty.  It has to do a default construction and then a move, where with the `piecewise_construct` we forward all the parameters into `emplace` and only have a single default constructor call.  In this case it probably wont matter, but I could see where it might if the class had a lot of members that need to be moved.

Comment: @NathanOliver in most cases compiler should be able to optimize out the unnecessary construction calls. And frankly writing the extra-long construction is not good for the code clarity and it's not worth ruining it even if there is some additional calls that compiler failed to optimize. That's being said, I agree that knowledge of such construction is important but it should be accompanied with clarification when it's worthwhile and important to use. Not just "here, use it".

Answer (score 7):

If you are using C++17 or later, replacing

```
// mp.emplace("abc", A());
```

with

```
mp.try_emplace("abc");
```

compiles fine.

The reason why `mp.emplace("abc", A());` produces a compile error is that the sub-expression `A()` constructs a new object of type `A` in `main()`'s scope and so `emplace()` expects to directly forward this new object as the argument into *some* `A` constructor, but there is no such constructor (said differently, somewhere inside the `emplace()` method's definition, there is something like the code `A(A())`, which is undefined).

As mentioned elsewhere, adding a move constructor to `class A` with the code `A(A&&) = default;` will also fix the compilation error (although this fix might not be an option with other, more complex classes). The reason why this removes the error is because there now exists a constructor that `emplace()` can forward this `A()` object into (as an argument). That is, the code `A(A())` becomes well-defined.